# Printing in one line the common text using comm cmd?

Tags: join, comm

I have 2 files that contain numbers_ID, status, descrpation  I want to join both files based on the numbers as

```
number_123, status1, status2
```

My file 1:

```
number_123,this car is under maintenance  
number_345,this car checked is done
number_356,this car is under main
```

My file 2:

```
number_123,hold  
number_345,done
```

I need to join only the existing number in both files as :

```
number_123,hold,this car is under maintenance    
number_345,done,this car checked is done
```

I used comm file1 file2 to find the common numbers but the file look like:

```
number_123,this car is under maintenance 
number_123,hold 
number_345,this car checked is done
number_345,done
```

How Can I print it in one line as

```
 number_123,hold,this car is under maintenance    
 number_345,done,this car checked is done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `comm` utility is used to compare whole lines between files.  What you want to do is to join on a particular field.

```
$ join -t, file2 file1
number_123,hold,this car is under maintenance
number_345,done,this car checked is done
```

This assumes that both files are sorted on the join field (the first comma-delimited column in each file).

If the files are not sorted, you may pre-sort them using

```
sort -t, -k1,1 -o file1 file1
sort -t, -k1,1 -o file2 file2
```

In `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you may also do the sort "on the fly":

```
join -t, <( sort -t, -k1,1 file2 ) <( sort -t, -k1,1 file1 )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and help, -join cmd is more suit to my problem than comm.